# Make a music bot to automatically become a speaker in stage channel using python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can I make my bot become a speaker using python?

```
voice_channel = self.bot.get_channel("ChanelID")
if voice_channel is not None:
    self.player = await voice_channel.connect(self_deaf=False, reconnect=True)
    self.player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=FFMPEG_LOCATION, source=RADIO_STREAM))
    logger.info("The bot has connected to the voice channel and started playing music.")
```

I tried the suggested solution, but it didn't help me.

```
if voice_channel is not None:
    self.player = await voice_channel.connect(self_deaf=False, reconnect=True)
    self.player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=FFMPEG_LOCATION, source=RADIO_STREAM))
    await self.stage_instance.edit(speaker=True)
    logger.info("Connecting to the voice channel and playing music.")
```

And this:

```
await voice_channel.request_to_speak()
await voice_channel.edit(suppress=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```py
if isinstance(voice_channel, discord.StageChannel):
    member = voice_channel.guild.me
    await member.edit(suppress=False)
```

Comment: You can edit your answer to correct the indentation :)